# Checkbox is checked then only append it to the div or else remove it if it is unchecked

Tags: jquery

Please look at the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6fsf8/

if the checkbox is checked then only i need to append it to the div  , if its unchecked then i need to remove it from the div .

I have tried this , but it is keep on appending it to the div .

```
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
    $("#fororders").append($(this).attr('value'));

}
```

And also is it possible that i should display them in a vertical order rather than horizontal order while appending it to the div .

You need to expand all the Accordians to see the checkboxes .
Could you please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: @MilindAnantwar no.. just expand all of those accordians..

Comment: sorry for the incomplete question , you need to expand all the Accordians to see the checkboxes .

Comment: But they would be unchecked by default. are you setting them from somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element is append because you don't remove it.

Try something like :

```
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{

    $("#fororders").append('<div id="something">'+$(this).attr('value')+'</div>');

}else{
    $('#something').remove();
}
```

To display your elements vertically, add the css property `display:block;`
This is some base CSS, you should not ask this here.

Comment: your solution seems good , thank you very very much , is it possible to push the latest checked to the top of the div ?? right now they are ending up at the end .

Comment: Yes, use prepend() instead of append() ;) But if you don't add it to a container they will be placed BEFORE your accordion

Comment: If the checkbox gets selecetd , Is it possible to get a CheckBox with that value  in place of a text

Comment: Yep, if I understand what you need, replace $("#fororders").append('<div id="something">'+$(this).attr('value')+'</div>');     with     
var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" value="'+$(this).attr('value')+'"/>'); $("#fororders").prepend(checkbox);

Comment: I need the checkbox with the selected value and in a different line .when i tried with your code its just displayed an empty checkbox .

Comment: Yes, my bad, you must add the attribute checked to the checkbox.
If you want it to a new line, write "<br/>" or add style="display:block;" to the checkbox

Comment: where must i add this  attribute checked to the checkbox.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="yourvalue" checked/>

Comment: Thank you very much , its displaying just an empty checkbox .

Comment: I have used var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox"  value="'+$(this).attr('value')+'" checked/>');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54219/discussion-between-preethi-jain-and-fc).

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
if(this.checked)
{
    $("#fororders").append($(this).attr('value'));

}
```

and instead of click you can use **change** event:

```
$(document).on("change", ":checkbox", function (e) {

if(this.checked)
{
    $("#fororders").append($(this).attr('value'));

}


});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6fsf8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the item from the `#fororders` div. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fsf8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the text in an element and then append that. That would make it easier for you to target it by `id` so as to be able to remove it later:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6fsf8/3/***

```
$(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function (e) {
    var v = $(this).val(); // cache the value
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // create a span with the same id as value and append it
        $("#fororders").append( $("<span>").attr("id", v).text(v) );
    } else {
        // target the span with the same id as value and remove it
        $("#fororders").find("span#" + v).remove();
    }

});
```